# как сделать редирект на личный кабинет google analitycs при помощи Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

У меня возникла задача, а именно как сделать редирект на личный кабинет  google analitycs  при помощи Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Для всех редиректов в Laravel есть глобальная функция redirect(). Вариант с away() предназначен специально для внешних URL, он не будет пытаться валидировать или как-то кодировать переданную ссылку. В общем, просто пишешь в методе контроллера примерно следующее:

```
return redirect()->away('https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/provision/');
```